Is Gallery view json formatting removed?
We are developing Intranet. It was developed successfully in sandbox. We have a list with gallery view formatting. We haven't customized it. We have selected that view and selected columns only.  we were ready to deploy everything on Production. We used ShareGate tool to migrate.
But Microsoft seems to have deployed new SharePoint List design and with that we are no longer able to see Gallery view on the view formatting. If we manually paste the formatting code from sandbox to production, it didn't work.
I tried creating a new list manually and check the same thing. But the formatting doesn't work.
Can someone confirm it is removed? If not is there any feature or anything we need to configure to bring that experience back?

Even if the list render has been upgraded to "Microsoft Lists" render since may 2024, gallery is still an option.
You can create and customize a SharePoint modern list with cards.



